# debug a python alexa type little ai

Tags: python, debugging, artificial-intelligence, alexa-skills-kit

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from time import ctime as t
from text_to_speech import save
import subprocess
import webbrowser
from translate import Translator
import random
from pygame import mixer

r= sr.Recognizer()

def record_audio(ask = False):
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        if ask:
            print(ask)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        voice_data = ''
        try:
            voice_data = r.recognize_google(audio , language= "en-us")
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            save("sorry i dont get that", "en", file="er1.mp3")
        except sr.RequestError:
            save('sorry service is down' , "en" , file="er2.mp3")
        return voice_data

def respond(voice_data):
    if 'what is your name' in voice_data :
        save("my name is alex", "en", file="rep1.mp3")
    if 'what time is it' in voice_data:
        speak(t())
    if 'search' in voice_data:
        search = record_audio('what do you want to search for?')
        url = 'https://google.com/search?q='+search
        webbrowser.get().open(url)
        speak("here what i found for" + search)
    if 'open' in voice_data:
        launch = record_audio(speak("what do you want to open"))
        subprocess.call(launch + '.exe')

    if 'translate' in voice_data:
        to_lan = record_audio(speak('enter code to which language you have to translate , hi for hindi , en for english , fr for french , de for german '))
        aud  = record_audio(speak('what you have to translate'))
        translator = Translator(to_lang = to_lan)
        translation = translator.translate(aud)
        speak(translation)

    if 'i am bored' in voice_data:
        reply = record_audio(speak('should i tell a joke or play music?'))
        if 'joke' in reply:
            jokee = random.choice(['I went to the doctor the other day and said: “Have you got anything for wind?” So he gave me a kite.' , 'Why do we tell actors to break a leg? Because every play has a cast' , 'Why don’t scientists trust atoms? Because they make up everything.'])
            speak(jokee)
            
        if 'music' in reply:
                # Starting the mixer 
                mixer.init() 
                
                # Loading the song 
                mixer.music.load("song.mp3") 
                
                # Setting the volume 
                mixer.music.set_volume(0.7) 
                
                # Start playing the song 
                mixer.music.play() 
                
                # infinite loop 
                while True: 
                    
                    speak("Press 'p' to pause, 'r' to resume") 
                    speak("Press 'e' to exit the program") 
                    query = input("  ") 
                    
                    if query == 'p': 
                
                        # Pausing the music 
                        mixer.music.pause()      
                    elif query == 'r': 
                
                        # Resuming the music 
                        mixer.music.unpause() 
                    elif query == 'e': 
                
                        # Stop the mixer 
                        mixer.music.stop() 
                        break
                    
while True:        
    save("how can i help you?" , "en" , file="reply.mp3")
    voice_data = record_audio()
    respond(voice_data)
```

Please help me in debuging this!

Here I am trying to get some audio in real time. Can anyone help me in analyzing it and write any functions?
Following there are several errors shown. Please ANSWER me only after running the code.
I think there is some problem but I am not able to find it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\My codes\alex\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import speech_recognition as sr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
PS F:\to do app> & C:/Users/gamea/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe "f:/My codes/alex/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\My codes\alex\main.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'speak' from 'text_to_speech' (C:\Users\gamea\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\text_to_speech\__init__.py)
PS F:\to do app> & C:/Users/gamea/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe "f:/My codes/alex/main.py"
pygame 2.2.0 (SDL 2.0.22, Python 3.11.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\My codes\alex\main.py", line 88, in <module>
    speak('how can i help you?')
    ^^^^^
PS F:\to do app> & C:/Users/gamea/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe "f:/My codes/alex/main.py"
pygame 2.2.0 (SDL 2.0.22, Python 3.11.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\My codes\alex\main.py", line 88, in <module>
    save("how can i help you?" , "en" , file="reply")
  File "C:\Users\gamea\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\text_to_speech\text_to_speech.py", line 15, 
in save
    raise ValueError(f"{file} is in a '{extension}' format, it should be in a '.mp3' format.")
ValueError: reply is in a '' format, it should be in a '.mp3' format.
PS F:\to do app> & C:/Users/gamea/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe "f:/My codes/alex/main.py"
pygame 2.2.0 (SDL 2.0.22, Python 3.11.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gamea\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 120, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\My codes\alex\main.py", line 89, in <module>
    voice_data = record_audio()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\gamea\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\gamea\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 122, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
PS F:\to do app> & C:/Users/gamea/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe "f:/My codes/alex/main.py"
pygame 2.2.0 (SDL 2.0.22, Python 3.11.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
result2:
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are missing the `pyaudio` package.  From the command line, you should be install with pip like

```
python -m pip install pyaudio
```

Other options are listed here: https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/